# Display custom tooltip over the column values in a cross table in Spotfire

Tags: tooltip, spotfire

When using Spotfire (v7.8.1), how would I display a custom tool tip over a cross table's column values?

While there is an option to customize tooltips for pie charts, I can't find one for the cross table visualization. Is there a custom expression that can edit the text on tool tip?

Any response is much appreciated!

Comment: What workaround did you use ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to control tooltips for tables visuals in Spotfire

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly control tooltips for a Spotfire CrossTable however you can hack extra info into a cell value by using `Concatenate()` and new line characters `\n`

```
UniqueConcatenate(Concatenate([CELL_VALUE],'\n',[TOOLTIP_VAL_1],'\n',[TOOLTIP_VAL_2]))
```

The value is wrapped in `UniqueConcatenate` since this counts as a aggregation function